# Error sending emails from a mail server relay type falling into the spam folder (using postfix)

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, spam, dkim, email-server

Here I show one of the emails that come to Yahoo, which are falling directly into SPAM folder. The SPF goes smoothly, the DKIM passes without problem, even DMARK passes without problem, but just keep falling in SPAM.

```
From Latibusiness Thu Jul 10 09:40:27 2014
X-Apparently-To: test2.koiosoft@yahoo.com via 98.139.244.156; Thu, 10 Jul 2014 16:40:26 +0000
Return-Path: <noresponder@latibusiness.com>
X-YahooFilteredBulk: 162.209.100.253
Received-SPF: pass (domain of latibusiness.com designates 162.209.100.253 as permitted sender)
X-YMailISG: wLiP2uYWLDunpOhluG01k2SiMy3jDGmECZgo81lftj3QxDNX
 P5LLPSYomr9isxrQgIFpLSiVzOJXj0mxuSY3WzFzs1GnRdWJN5U8nAnNAOIL
 jnwAM1V1D8EUOh43tAX5Xp07Ldwy9Omuj7RBBG5BGUbwa0LdOk_Az73TzH9k
 aV2ST6_jdtOzxv_zZ_yUgiYt577w.p6xnjAAJZaAC2PuoAUDKIUIm.CAhsQ1
 vcYys2MbW.pvqQbrE8Xy9xdAt0RpdOhuLDxdVUz9SSN5f.JUe_ZMMe8bsGJ4
 0gM5nRRpNe9SbusAMC63C_fe0RapOJhX89695u1yXyty.6cd.mYUf_1jm2.y
 _HlJ2R9hhQgkMluzBf2gJmicgvAVWAhC.y_pWhn0aNhjpHGDt0vFNkv3G6uL
 vI6vEySWrsUEDFN1TPVfrlwlWSCYIf3DZQttg1kKIgEmmGhi_gZf57RYj.Oj
 _9dL01TkSNcbi7HTxvW8ZipK_yyVLFHucSF0B_swukDw6.5RUh4QL9G9f98g
 f_vdddXRiQuPPp7nHuSgZetOfS1Y8FAb9CN.3hxcAJ9ZQlSQDra1cjf5niPO
 8X1Wq7Av0J0I79X.xrEPCtRi67vLdJaUNAYOX2OJJcveq_4v.AEUYnwmKSnZ
 NWoAs01PXtc2iwLktCOtFBnCQsg8fkw.cabS4Iefc1T6_0TEjTFa7IpzvHNh
 BtRA9GYUCrUpn4_mw59qGGWxMdgldUCDRqZluz0aAK4zIsjlol1TIEsUZMod
 khsq65L_Ehbvcuo7W0JZP9iG12iCPmnzzIqbI8GPdy2RQnEpZ5BzEhtcqHWe
 2W370HNfAFGTbwefp6SAQ7kDX4aaSM.ZJ39VMa5xUI2CSisdgj1JvlA3bfxm
 SL3a3.dYAcEmXV1kBY91NQTfRIDoWBIvjuj9q49.ybuc7Yae8Pr9o_p_hLjT
 5MFchx9_hMZddonJKlZSpyOfDSXDxUEu6gYRYFo7pxEJPZDJv3tutQv3xRPX
 R__nLQPyY15UKz9COjzlU6tnVJNE6zZ_4ze7x46JW54sYm8TiGuyHLS58zc6
 AonrGG19sH3AdwOjdXRnpqD1BkgvZ4siXQ8TScJtq3z4A5dDdXkkibb1UQHB
 7OYKVpxwsNMjEb_DWUYYAYtLfNnrnhcupGedYXmh.cOvMzlRx_1akElLCBJE
 nw3_2gEEOaiFqnTsscVV3KeQUJdQA5T8ITO50jWSDnlBg.xPmrHXoB_r2_b0
 7ntKUQdQEKdANK3MGGHPodInqesbBjusp_FjDoaglPRZqah95HnbubSuUzvH
 fk3ESSZSkN8pSX3nTEFZi_EH_c657yY017OhuhXbREAhZk3kqXncQWroQKkX
 2zVO.9wGAg--
X-Originating-IP: [162.209.100.253]
Authentication-Results: mta1306.mail.bf1.yahoo.com  from=latibusiness.com; domainkeys=neutral (no sig);  from=latibusiness.com; dkim=pass (ok)
Received: from 127.0.0.1  (EHLO relay.latibusiness.com) (162.209.100.253)
  by mta1306.mail.bf1.yahoo.com with SMTP; Thu, 10 Jul 2014 16:40:13 +0000
Received: from latibusiness.com (latibusiness.com [162.209.96.44])
    by relay.latibusiness.com (Postfix) with SMTP id 88C72726FA
    for <test2.koiosoft@yahoo.com>; Thu, 10 Jul 2014 16:40:46 +0000 (UTC)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=latibusiness.com;
    s=mail; t=1405010447;
    bh=N9J2OG1k7HP6ioWA71gFs3KV4CEv5Uijwfr7H5LBAlQ=;
    h=Date:To:Subject:From:From;
    b=nMDwJpd5TYaKFj6nQGYSHfvKpDd84JIfPk6x1LR05kzfBjo+z/9qB8OEccb9uz/Bu
     C/XcOCw0vSIK8aCrnc10Woa2wDIImmPog6BNQdOPD2sGrwUBAOer4BKbniwN+ylmip
     4IKH44N7pBVYxOJ3VToH8N3/jsrNcllDYBhxOYwg=
Received: by latibusiness.com (sSMTP sendmail emulation); Thu, 10 Jul 2014 16:40:27 +0000
Date: Thu, 10 Jul 2014 16:40:27 +0000
To: test2.koiosoft@yahoo.com
Subject: Otro subject distinto
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 1001:email.php
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
From: Latibusiness <noresponder@latibusiness.com>
X-Mailer: PHP/5.4.6-1ubuntu1.7
Content-Length: 46
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try sending an email to a different email service?

If Yahoo has detected the sender as spam before, perhaps there is now an email rule that moves all mail from that sender into the spam folder.

Have you tried sending to a Gmail address or other email provider?

Comment: Nop.  The test was done to assess post newly created precisely without the noise of an old account

Comment: In my past experience, it may take someday/some legitimate emails for yahoo to trust the email sending from your IP.

Answer (score 1):

Even with valid **rDNS**, **SPF** and  **DKIM**, Yahoo still could place your email to their spam folder. The possible reason is your IP address listed in Yahoo blacklist because previous webmaster/admin sent spam with your IP.

In my past experience with this provider, it may take someday/some legitimate emails in order to rebuild trusted relationship with Yahoo MX. Some advice I've taken in that time is fill out
[**Yahoo! Mail Bulk Sender Form**](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/postmaster/bulkv2.html). It allows you to tell yahoo what kind of mail server setup you have, so that they can route your emails to the appropriate folder.

Comment: OK, and why Outlook.com has same problem?  Gmail is right!!! =(

Comment: Different provider has different rules. In the past, I also had trouble with outlook.com but I ignore it because the that domain is just small subset of my clients.

Answer (score 0):

I added a TXT-SPF record to allow verification by the destination mailserver.

```
@    TXT    "v=spf1 include:_spf.telenet.be a:pieterjan.pro ~all"
```

With this record in place, the mails I send are going directly to the inbox instead of the spam.

I think that mailservers are filtering spam by challenging the from-field (eg. no-reply@pieterjan.pro) to the DNS-records associated to the appearing domain-name (pieterjan.pro).

If the DNS of pieterjan.pro contains the above record, the mailserver trusts emails sent from the other mailhub (eg. smtp.telenet.be) whilst the from-field is altered.